# sendkeys error chrome driver emoji (ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xaml

tengo una aplicación que tiene un richTextBox en donde introduzco letra y emojis , luego con un sendkeys trato de enviar el contenido a una web que tiene un input y el foco sobre el y el error que me da es, ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP, tendría alguna otra opción de copiar y pegar el contenido?

Comment: pero es una app que ejecuta en un mobile ? esa web que mencionas tiene que ser visualizada por el usuario, el cual ve lo que se completa, o solo requieres poner navegarla para despues extraer algo de esta

Comment: de casualidad la pagina tiene un captcha?

Comment: no tiene captcha, no es en mobile es desktop, lo que pasa es que tengo un formulario con un Richtextbox, quiero poder enviar el contenido a otra pantalla en donde tengo una web incrustada tipo webview que tiene un input con el foco activo pero al hacerlo con sendkeys me da ese error, no importa si soluciono lo del error lo que me interesa es poder copiar y pegar el contenido de un lugar a otro vía código.